# I am getting an error when trying to install DataComputing in R. Why?

Tags: r

When trying to install DataComputing with the command: 
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("DataComputing/DataComputing")

I receive the error:
Warning: package ‘ggplot2’ was built under R version 3.2.4
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  namespace ‘nlme’ 3.1-122 is being loaded, but >= 3.1.123 is required
Error : package ‘car’ could not be loaded
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘DataComputing’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/DataComputing’
Error: Command failed (1)

What do I do? Thank you

Comment: Looks like you need to update/install the dependencies ggplot2, nlme, and car.